# Capture keycode on input's with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I have a page with many text input's. All input's share the same class for many reasons.

Now I am trying to capture a the ESC button when an input is focused and alert if the input has value or not.

Now this logically works only for the first field. After the first field, since all input's share the same class, when I press ESC button it gives you the value of the very first input.

So how can I say that I'm talking for the second, fifth or whatever input I am pressing ESC on.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5e9W/

The first input works fine, the second input thought; when you press ESC it gives you the values of the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to bind the `keyup` event to the elements with your class, rather than the `document`. Then `this` will refer to the element with focus:

```
$(".gp").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 27) {
        if(this.value.length > 0) {
            //Has a value!
        }
        else {
            //Empty!
        }
    }
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5e9W/1/). Note that I've used the [`which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property of the event object, which jQuery exposes to deal with browser differences between `keyCode` and `charCode`.

**Update** based on comments

If you do need to handle this at the `document` level, you can use the [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method to narrow down your selection of `.gp` elements to the one which has focus:

```
if (gj.has(":focus").val() != 0) { //...
```

Here's [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5e9W/3/).

Comment: It's not possible to be wrapped in document keyup? It's an entire webapp which includes alot in that document keyup.

Comment: It should be possible, but probably not as efficient as binding the event handler to the elements themselves. See my edit (assuming I've understood what you need...)

Comment: Okay found my actual problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kjCs3/ My inputs have attached an autocomplete. The jquery autocomplete gives itself the keycodes, thus making the keybind's not to work properly. Check out the fiddle

Comment: That's the reason I couldn't figure it out myself, because before I come to SO I check every possible solution.

Comment: Well I'm glad you figured it out in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do -

```
$(".gp").keyup(function (e) {
     if ($(this).is(":focus") && (e.keyCode == 27)) {
         if ($(this).val() != 0){
             alert('full');
               $(this).val('');
         }else{
             alert('empty');}
    }
});
```

Which will only respond to the `keyup` event of elements with the 'gp' class, you can then use `this` to access the relevant element.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/uqS72/2/

Comment: It's not possible to be in document keyup?